# cosmos-sdk decimal precision for coins onchain

Tags: tendermint, cosmos-sdk

Am building a cosmos-sdk chain and was wondering what the official support was for coin's decimal precision on a cosmos chain either being minted via a peg or seeded via genesis as the primary staking/demon token.

We would like to support 10**18 as this matches ethereum and just want to get clarity on this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you checked these links regarding issue fixed? [Increasing decimal precision to 18](https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/pull/3315) | [Usage of sdk.Decimals for sdk.Coins](https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/issues/3251) 

and the appropriate type for ]Dec_Coin.go](https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/blob/master/types/dec_coin.go)

Answer (score 1):

`Coin.Amount` used throughout the SDK [is an `int`](https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/blob/afda62174fe6531b2a40c595a4d9396c28e8b391/types/coin.pb.go#L30). There is a [`DecCoin`](https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/blob/6344d626db1fbdba5e0f67425703c1584021bf5b/types/dec_coin.go#L14), but it doesn't seem to be used that much.

Practically speaking, coins are integer values and the upper limit seems to be `10**76` when added to genesis with `appd add-genesis-account`. However, after the chain has started, having on balance more than `10**76` works fine.

Comment: Yeah looks like we have actually found an issue in the sdk staking.go code. Have a look at this: https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/issues/8357

Comment: Yep, seems like the limit specifically on staking is much lower.

Answer (score 1):

The Bank Module and subsequent Coin type contain metadata capabilities that include decimals as outlined in [ADR-024-coin-metadata](https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/blob/master/docs/architecture/adr-024-coin-metadata.md).

The relevant types are as follows:

```golang
message DenomUnit {
  string denom    = 1;
  uint32 exponent = 2;  
  repeated string aliases = 3;
}

message Metadata {
  string description = 1;
  repeated DenomUnit denom_units = 2;
  string base = 3;
  string display = 4;
}
```

And the example of the  $ATOM, which has 6 decimals, is given here:

```json
{
  "description": "The native staking token of the Cosmos Hub.",
  "denom_units": [
    {
      "denom": "uatom",
      "exponent": 0,
      "aliases": [
        "microatom"
      ],
    },
    {
      "denom": "matom",
      "exponent": 3,
      "aliases": [
        "milliatom"
      ]
    },
    {
      "denom": "atom",
      "exponent": 6,
    }
  ],
  "base": "uatom",
  "display": "atom",
}
```